# Python and Google App Engine access issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I followed the install for GAE and tried a tutorial. Getting:

```
The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Error 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\app\\django\\pyyaml-3.10-py2.7-win32.egg-tmp\\_yaml.pyd'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  C:\Users\User\Documents\app\django

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

PYTHON_EGG_CACHE is changed away from the AppData folder which was causing issues as per every other SO solution. 
I checked permissions for the user and Admin, full control. I am running SDK as administrator.

Comment: Could you give the URL to that tutorial?  Maybe we can help debug it...

Comment: just found a solution, posted it

Answer (score 0):

The error is with pyyaml, to fix this uninstall pyyaml and reinstall with -Z

I did:

```
easy_install -Z pyyaml
```

Thanks to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9069